# Django: Two ManyToManyField to the same model

Tags: django

This is my code:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='title', unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='content')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    favourite_users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                             blank=True, null=True)
```

this model has a ForeignKey and a ManyToManyField to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, now if I have a settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL instance named 'user', how can I get the questions this user writes and questions this user likes? I have tried 'user.question_set.all()', but it doesn't work, maybe I should set related_name, like this:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='questions')
favourite_users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                         related_name='favourite_questions',
                                         blank=True, null=True)
```

and then use: user.questions.all() and user.favourite_questions.all() to get questions asked and favourited by user. but I am not sure if it is true. so I want to know if there is any good way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried `'user.question_set.all()'`, but it doesn't work

As you are using a custom auth model, you should use [`get_user_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) to fetch the model that the authentication framework is using:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

user_model = get_user_model()
```

To fetch the questions for a particular user:

```
user_model = get_user_model()
user = user_model.objects.get(pk=1)  # Now this is not the "normal" User

user_questions = Question.objects.filter(author=user)
user_favorites = Question.objects.filter(favorite_users=user)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, user is not User, user is an instance of settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,the Question model has a ForeignKey and a ManyToManyField to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, so if I use user.question_set.all(), the django doesn't know which field(the field author or favourite_users) the QuerySet should contain . I want to know if setting 'related_name' is a good way to solve this problem

Comment: From the name `question` in `question_set` django knows which field you are looking for. Use [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) for customizing the manager for "reverse" relationships. You should not use `User` (from `django.contrib.auth. models`), but instead use the `get_user_model()` method in your queries, since you are using custom auth models.

Comment: you misunderstand me, if Question only has an ManyToManyField to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, then you use 'question_set', ok, django knows which field the QuerySet should contain, but if Question has two ManyToManyField(ForeignKey is identical in this situation) to settings.AUTH_MODEL_FIELD ,then you use 'question_set', how can django figure out which field the QuerySet should contain?

Comment: `question_set` will only work for those models that have a reverse relationship to `Question`, it will not work for an instance of the `Question` object.

Comment: I should improve my English, I have found the solution, just set related_name, anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get all questions asked by a certain user, use `Question.objects.filter(author=user)`. Similarly, to get all questions favorited by a certain user, use `Question.objects.filter(favourite_users=user)`.

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) contains some very helpful examples of lookups across many-to-many relationships.